# Given a norm, show a map is Affine

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces, affine-geometry, rigid-transformation

So I have this problem:

Let $\|v\|_1=|x|+|y|$ be a norm in the plane, if $v=(x,y)$.

> Now I'm asked to show that, if $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $ satisfies $\|T(v)-T(u)\|_1=\|v-u\|_1$, then $T$ is of the type $T(v)=p+A(v)$ with $A$ a linear map.

I am not quite sure where to start, I have worked for some time with properties of norms, and I don't arrive anywhere. 
It may be similar in some way to proving that a rigid motion satisfying that norm given is affine... but I can't find the way to prove this. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Are there any additional assumptions on the map $T$?

Comment: The title of the exercise does not include any more conditions on the map T,  appart from the fact that satisfies that condition of the norm I said in the question. I suppose it could be a rigid motion map, because it kind of preserves distance, but I can't really say anything more about T.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Note that $X=(\mathbb{R}^2, d)$ is a metric space where
$d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. Hence $T$ is an isometry.

(2) Assume that
$$ \| v-u\| +\|u-x\|=\|v-x\|$$

Then $$ \| Tv-Tu\| +\|Tu-Tx\|=\|Tv-Tx\| $$

(3) If $e_i$ is a canonical basis, then $c(t)=te_1$ is unique
shortest path from $(0,0)$ to $e_1$.

If $T(0,0)=(0,0)$, then $Te_1\in \{\pm e_i\}$.

If $Te_1=e_1$ and $Te_2=-e_1$, then $(0,0)$ is a unique mid point between $e_1$ and $-e_1$.

Hence $T(t,t)=(0,0)$ where $0\leq t\leq 1$. It is a contradiction.

If $Te_2=e_2$, then $TA=A$ where $A=
 \{ (t,t)|0\leq t\leq \}$.

$\| T(0,0)-T(t,t)\| =\|(t,t)\|$ so that $T$ is identity on $A$.
Hence $T$ is identity on $\mathbb{Z}^2$

For $t>0$, $A_t=t\cdot \mathbb{Z}^2$. Since $T(te_i)=te_i$, by
similar argument, $T$ is identity on $A_t$ so that $T$ is
identity.

For general $T$, set $S(x)=T(x)-T(0,0)$ so that $S(0,0)=(0,0)$.
Hence $S$ is identity. That is, $T(x)=x+ T(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the Mazur-Ulam theorem: a surjective isometry between normed linear spaces must be an affine map. There is a Wikipedia stub on the subject, but it's not very helpful. Check out [this short and rather elegant proof](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/mazurulam.pdf) instead.

The problem here is that surjectivity is not assumed, which is the hole I intend to fill.

I first claim that $\operatorname{Range} T$ is orthogonally convex, meaning that its intersections with horizontal or vertical lines are convex. To prove this, note that for $\lambda \in [0, 1]$,
$$S[(x_1, y); \lambda|x_1 - x_2|] \cap S[(x_2, y); (1 - \lambda)|x_1 - x_2|] = \lbrace (\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2, y) \rbrace.$$
(It's not as painful as it looks.) So, if $T(p) = (x_1, y)$ and $T(q) = (x_2, y)$, but
$$(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2, y) \notin \operatorname{Range} T$$
then
$$S[p; \lambda|x_1 - x_2|] \cap S[q; (1 - \lambda)|x_1 - x_2|] \subseteq T^{-1} \lbrace (\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2, y) \rbrace = \emptyset.$$
But, the only way that two spheres can have non-empty intersection is if the distance between the centres is greater than the sum of their radii, in other words,
$$|x_1 - x_2| = \lambda|x_1 - x_2| + (1 - \lambda)|x_1 - x_2| < \|p - q\| = \|(x_1, y) - (x_2, y)\| = |x_1 - x_2|,$$
which is a contradiction. Hence $(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2, y) \in \operatorname{Range} T$, proving horizontal convexity. Vertical convexity follows by a similar argument.

Obviously, $\operatorname{Range} T$ is not a singleton. This means, $\operatorname{Range} T$ must contain a non-trivial horizontal or vertical line segment. We will assume it is a vertical line segment, and the other case will be analogous.

Let $y_1, y_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(y_1, y_2 \pm \varepsilon) \in \operatorname{Range} T$. Then, for any $r > \varepsilon$,
$$S[(y_1, y_2 + \varepsilon); r] \cap S[(y_1, y_2 - \varepsilon); r] = \lbrace (y_1 + r - \varepsilon, y_2), (y_1 - r + \varepsilon, y_2) \rbrace.$$
Let $p, q \in \Bbb{R}^2$ such that $Tp = (y_1, y_2 + \varepsilon)$ and $Tq = (y_1, y_2 - \varepsilon)$. Then,
$$S[p; r] \cap S[q; r] \subseteq T^{-1}\lbrace (y_1 + r - \varepsilon, y_2), (y_1 - r + \varepsilon, y_2) \rbrace,$$
which is finite. As above, we cannot have $S[p; r] \cap S[q; r] = \emptyset$, as this would lead to $r < \varepsilon$. If it were a singleton, then this would imply $r = \varepsilon$. So, $S[p; r] \cap S[q; r]$ is a doubleton, and so $(y_1 \pm (r - \varepsilon), y_2) \in \operatorname{Range} T$. This is true for all $r > \varepsilon$, so the whole horizontal line $y = y_2$ is contained in $\operatorname{Range} T$.

This now puts $(y_1, y_2)$ on a non-trivial horizontal line segment contained in $\operatorname{Range} T$, so an analogous argument shows that both the vertical line $x = y_1$ and horizontal line $y = y_2$ are contained in $\operatorname{Range} T$. From applying this argument to other points along these lines, we easily see that $\operatorname{Range} T = \Bbb{R}^2$.